# Is ExternalInterface really slow with long strings?

Tags: flash, delphi, actionscript-2, delphi-7, externalinterface

I have an Flash10/ActionScript2 application embedded in a Delphi shell.
I need to send a long string to Delphi. I was using fscommand until now, but ExternalInterface is synchronous so I'd like to use it in my application.

Everything is fine except for one thing : I send a long string - an xml string formatted by Flash - to Delphi. And this command is taking an extremely long time (approx. 2 minutes).

Has anyone an idea about limits with ExternalInterface or with its use in Delphi?

Thanks!

Comment: how big is your string? consider compressing it.

Comment: 660 000 chars. Any idea how to compress a string in AS2 ?

Comment: Try assigning the xml to a _root property and retrieve it through GetVariable(). ExternalInterface() does some pretty ugly stuff behind the scene. It is buggy too.

Comment: @EmilSchn sorry, AS is not on my menu, but have a look at http://code.google.com/p/calista/source/browse/trunk/AS3/src/calista/util/LZW.as?r=3

Comment: I've never used flash with Delphi, but I have many times with C#/VisualStudio.  I've sent a 2mb XML file (much larger than yours) and it takes about 300ms.  Make sure you're delay isn't in parsing that string - which is usually where the slowdowns come from.   At one point I was printing that xml text out to the screen for debugging purposes, and it changed the time from 300ms to 72 seconds!

Comment: I tried cleong's method. It made me realise that it's not really the time when the command is sent. The problem is that Delphi is getting the handle and Flash is not responding anymore (or really slowly) when Delphi makes big changes.

Comment: Can you put something together which compares the performance of communications with a long String vs. an equally long XML String?  I don't think AS2 is particularly good with handling big XML files - that might be your issue, rather than ExternalInterface.